Selected vertex appearance settings
When I select 2 vertices, it looks like a lot of edges are selected.
I am using blender 4.1

Are there any preferences to avoid this?
like reduce its gradient radius

Hello, actually only the edge between the 2 vertices is selected

Sure, that's why I say it looks like..

It's always been like that. The connecting edges to the selected vertex get a slight highlight halfway to easily help you visualize the topolgy, so you know they are really connected. It will help you identify overlapping vertices or edges because they don't get this smooth highlighting.

Thank you for the response. It would be perfect if there was a way to reduce its gradient radius.
